# Constraining associated type in supertrait

Tags: rust, traits

In the following (very much simplified) example I have a `UnboundBuffer` and a `BoundBuffer` trait. `UnboundBuffer` can be bound to `Memory` to create a `BoundBuffer`. This binding is done through the `MemoryBindable` supertrait, so it needs to be constrained further in `UnboundBuffer`, otherwise `Device::allocate_buffer` does not understand that the `MemoryBindable::bind()` method really returns a `BoundBuffer` that is the same as `Api::BoundBuffer`.

I am having trouble with getting the constraint on `UnboundBuffer` right. I've tried `Self::Bound: BoundBuffer`, `Self::Bound: BoundBuffer<Api = Self::Api>` and `Self::Bound: <Self::Api as Api>::BoundBuffer`, each of which generate their own errors, which I stuggle to fully understand if I'm honest. How can I properly constrain `UnboundBuffer` so that methods like `Device::allocate_buffer` can be written?

The following example code does not have any extra constraints applied, so the error happens in `Device::allocate_buffer`.

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8be1907b4995b6a07f4d31cd2bc55cbe)

```rust
use std::sync::{Weak, Arc};

struct Error;

trait Api {
    type BoundBuffer: BoundBuffer<Api = Self> + 'static;
    type Device: Device<Api = Self> + 'static;
    type Memory: Memory<Api = Self> + 'static;
    type UnboundBuffer: UnboundBuffer<Api = Self> + 'static;
}

trait ApiComponent {
    type Api: Api;
}

trait Memory: ApiComponent + Sized
    where Self::Api: Api<Memory = Self> {
    fn new(device: Arc<<Self::Api as Api>::Device>) -> Result<Self, Error>;
}

trait MemoryBindable: ApiComponent + Sized {
    type Bound: MemoryBound;
    fn bind(&mut self, memory: Arc<<Self::Api as Api>::Memory>) -> Self::Bound;
}

trait MemoryBound: ApiComponent + Sized {
    fn memory(&self) -> &Arc<<Self::Api as Api>::Memory>;
}

trait BoundBuffer: MemoryBound
    where Self::Api: Api<BoundBuffer = Self> {
    fn new(unbound: <Self::Api as Api>::UnboundBuffer, memory: Arc<<Self::Api as Api>::Memory>) -> Self;
}

trait UnboundBuffer: MemoryBindable
    where Self::Api: Api<UnboundBuffer = Self> {
    fn new(device: Arc<<Self::Api as Api>::Device>) -> Result<Self, Error>;
}

trait Device: ApiComponent + Sized 
    where Self::Api: Api<Device = Self> {
    fn new() -> Result<Arc<Self>, Error>;
    fn this(&self) -> &Weak<Self>;

    fn allocate_buffer(&self) -> Result<<Self::Api as Api>::BoundBuffer, Error> {
        let mut buffer = self.create_buffer()?;
        let memory = Arc::new(self.create_memory()?);
        let buffer = buffer.bind(memory);
        Ok(buffer)
    }

    fn create_buffer(&self) -> Result<<Self::Api as Api>::UnboundBuffer, Error> {
        <Self::Api as Api>::UnboundBuffer::new(self.this().upgrade().unwrap())
    }
    
    fn create_memory(&self) -> Result<<Self::Api as Api>::Memory, Error> {
        <Self::Api as Api>::Memory::new(self.this().upgrade().unwrap())
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really need this level of abstraction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a definition that works:

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Weak};

struct Error;

trait Api {
    type BoundBuffer: BoundBuffer<Api = Self> + 'static;
    type Device: Device<Api = Self> + 'static;
    type Memory: Memory<Api = Self> + 'static;
    type UnboundBuffer: UnboundBuffer<Api = Self, Bound = Self::BoundBuffer> + 'static;
}

trait ApiComponent {
    type Api: Api;
}

trait Memory: ApiComponent + Sized
where
    Self::Api: Api<Memory = Self>,
{
    fn new(device: Arc<<Self::Api as Api>::Device>) -> Result<Self, Error>;
}

trait MemoryBindable: ApiComponent + Sized {
    type Bound: MemoryBound<Api = Self::Api>;
    fn bind(&mut self, memory: Arc<<Self::Api as Api>::Memory>) -> Self::Bound;
}

trait MemoryBound: ApiComponent + Sized {
    fn memory(&self) -> &Arc<<Self::Api as Api>::Memory>;
}

trait BoundBuffer: MemoryBound
where
    Self::Api: Api<BoundBuffer = Self>,
{
    fn new(
        unbound: <Self::Api as Api>::UnboundBuffer,
        memory: Arc<<Self::Api as Api>::Memory>,
    ) -> Self;
}

trait UnboundBuffer: MemoryBindable
where
    Self::Api: Api<UnboundBuffer = Self, BoundBuffer = Self::Bound>,
{
    fn new(device: Arc<<Self::Api as Api>::Device>) -> Result<Self, Error>;
}

trait Device: ApiComponent + Sized
where
    Self::Api: Api<Device = Self>,
{
    fn new() -> Result<Arc<Self>, Error>;
    fn this(&self) -> &Weak<Self>;

    fn allocate_buffer(&self) -> Result<<Self::Api as Api>::BoundBuffer, Error> {
        let mut buffer = self.create_buffer()?;
        let memory = Arc::new(self.create_memory()?);
        let buffer = buffer.bind(memory);
        Ok(buffer)
    }

    fn create_buffer(&self) -> Result<<Self::Api as Api>::UnboundBuffer, Error> {
        <Self::Api as Api>::UnboundBuffer::new(self.this().upgrade().unwrap())
    }

    fn create_memory(&self) -> Result<<Self::Api as Api>::Memory, Error> {
        <Self::Api as Api>::Memory::new(self.this().upgrade().unwrap())
    }
}
```